# Is it possible to change logical operator of the conditional statement in js programmatically?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have two almost identical functions except for one difference, the logical operator in `if`.

I cannot write  `<=` as I need to search for equal spots in whole array and, only if not found, then for `<` spots.

```
// === in if
for (let i = 0; i < res.potentialFreeSpots.length; i++) {
  let freeSpotLength = Math.round(
    Math.abs(res.potentialFreeSpots[i]["end"] - res.potentialFreeSpots[i]["start"]) / 60000
  );
  if (credentials.serviceTimeConsumption === freeSpotLength) {
    return formFreeSpot(res.potentialFreeSpots[i]["start"], res.excludedTimes);
  }
}

// < in if
for (let i = 0; i < res.potentialFreeSpots.length; i++) {
  let freeSpotLength = Math.round(
    Math.abs(res.potentialFreeSpots[i]["end"] - res.potentialFreeSpots[i]["start"]) / 60000
  );
  if (credentials.serviceTimeConsumption < freeSpotLength) {
    return formFreeSpot(res.potentialFreeSpots[i]["start"], res.excludedTimes);
  }
}
```

Comment: If your code works and you seek improvements or constructive criticism, [codereview.se] would be a better fit to ask.

Comment: What do you mean 'how to optimize this.' What are you tryinf to do with this code?

Comment: I am trying to reduce these 2 functions into one, if it is possible of course... Need to understand if it is possible at all...

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Amy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this code needs some improvements at all. Let's make it right, base on @farvilain response.

As far as I can see res.potentialFreeSpots is a collection. Based on that we can use collection methods such as forEach, map, some, find and so on.

```
const doSomething = comparator => {
   if (!res. potentialFreeSpots) {
     return false;
   }

   const freeSpot = res.potentialFreeSpots
     .find(freeSpot => {
        const freeSpotLength = Math.round(Math.abs(freeSpot['end'] - freeSpot['start']) / 60000);

        return comparator(freeSpotLength, credentials.serviceTimeConsumption);
     });

   return formFreeSpot(freeSpot['start'], res.excludedTimes);
}
```

where comparator is a function so you can invoke it just like in @farvilain example

```
doSomething((a, b) => a === b));
doSomething((a, b) => a < b));
```

this way of solving this problem makes it more readable and easier to test.

Comment: Thank you, @Nubzor! Really valuable reply, will dive deeper into it!

Answer (score 4):

Just do it functionnal. Mimimum modification to make it works seems:

```
function something(compare){
    for (let i = 0; i < res.potentialFreeSpots.length; i++) {
      let freeSpotLength = Math.round(
        Math.abs(res.potentialFreeSpots[i]["end"] - res.potentialFreeSpots[i]["start"]) / 60000
      );
      if ( compare(credentials.serviceTimeConsumption, reeSpotLength)) {
        return formFreeSpot(res.potentialFreeSpots[i]["start"], res.excludedTimes);
      }
    }
}
```

Now call it like

```
something( (a,b) => a === b )
```

or

```
something( (a,b) => a < b )
```

Comment: Oh, this seems like a beautiful option, cool thank you! If somebody could advise more for educational purpose, i would be really thankful!

Comment: Just a proposal: read docs about functionnal programming or code like Arrays.filter, .... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter